# Classifying critical points based on Hessian matrix values

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

[image]

In this, at the critical points, I'm getting the following values of Hessian matrix.
H(0,0) = 20
H(-5/3,0) = 40/3
H(-1,2) = -16
H(-1,-2) = -16

Based on these, how did they classify the critical points as local max, local min or saddle point?

And how to check for global optimum points. By letting x and y approach infinity and then comparing the function values (which equals infinity) to function values at critical points?

Comment: here are some Infos to the second derivative test http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Comment: Okay, so the principal minors I get are the following - At (0,0) - 10, 20. Since both positive, so positive definite and hence local minimum. Similarly, at (-1,-2), I get -2,-16 as principal minors. So, saddle point. Is this correct?

Comment: it Looks good to me

Comment: Okay. And can you also see if my reasoning for global min and max is correct in the question above (edited version)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_two_variables

Comment: we have $$-\infty<h(x,y)<+\infty$$

Comment: Okay, thankyou guys.